# Does a minor major 6th chord exist?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I'm playing some chords from a song that goes Fm (F, A♭, C, F on guitar), Fmin7 (E♭, A♭, C, F), and a chord I don't know what to call that uses D, A♭, C, F. This appears to be similar to an Fmin/maj7 chord but with a major 6th instead of a 7th. Could this be called an Fmin/maj6, or would I need to call it something else?

Comment: You could describe this as a descending bass line with a simple `Fm` on top. What happens after the third chord? Depending on where this continues to change how to analyze the chords.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure why F-Ab-C-D would be considered closer to **FmM7** than **Fm7**; in any event, your chord is an **Fm6** chord. You could also interpret the chord D-F-Ab-C as a **Dm7b5**, or half-diminished chord.

The minor/major part of **FmM7** indicates that the chord is an **Fm** chord with a major 7th, to distinguish it from an **Fm7** with a minor 7th; note that the "minor" in **Fm7** does *not* refer to the 7th, though, but to the minor quality of the **Fm** triad.

There is such a thing as an **FmM13** chord, which would be spelled F-Ab-C-E-G-B-D, or possibly encountered as something like F-Ab-E-D.

Comment: But the 6th here is major, no? Wouldn't Fm6 imply that both the triad and 6th are minor?

Comment: The **m** only applies to the underlying triad. If the 6th were minor, you might have an **Fm(b6)**, but this would be a very unusual chord: the b6 is enharmonic to a #5, and would clash with the 5th of the **Fm** (F-Ab-C-Db).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it different for Fm7, where both the triad and 7th would be minor?

Comment: No, the **m** only applies to the triad. Chord nomenclature always gives the triad quality first, the **Fm** part, followed by a 7 if the chord is a 7th chord (or a 6 or 6/9). A **7** indicates a b7 by convention, and a **M7** indicates a natural 7. This can be a little confusing; some people like to reference the Mixolydian scale instead of the major scale with chord names for this reason. Note that for major quality chords there is usually no **M** associated with the triad. So an F major chord is an **F**, not an **FM**, and a dominant 7th F major chord is **F7**, not **FM7**.

Comment: Excellent answer. +1. I used to query why a m6 chord actually featured a M6 note! Apart from the fact that a minor triad with a m6 note added doesn't sound good, that M6 could easily be construed as the very note found in the *melodic* minor scale. Thus, it's O.K!

Comment: The context strongly influences whether a chord sounds "good". The notes of a C minor triad with an added m6 (Ab) is an alternative way of voicing a AbM7 chord, which _does_ sound good in the right context.

Comment: Wait, if that's the case, David, shouldn't F7 signal a major F flat 7 chord, because you said major chords don't have an M associated with them and 7's without an M are b7 by convention?

Comment: @コナーゲティ -- that's right, and I mentioned that a couple of comments up in the thread. **F7** is F-A-C-Eb, an F triad with an added minor 7th above the F (the Eb). Nobody calls these F flat 7 chords, and you almost always see it written as **F7**. I have seen it written as **FMm7** on rare occasions, where the M indicates a major triad and the m indicates a minor 7, but that is an extremely uncommon notation in my experience. I've never seen **FM** alone to indicate a major triad, always simply **F**. **FM7** is F-A-C-E, with the major 7th above the F.

Comment: Y'know what, I somehow mixed up that a dominant 7th chord was a major triad and a minor 7th. That makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: What would a minor triad with a minor 6th be called? Fm(b6)?

Comment: You could call it that; see my very first comment under the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the lowest note of each chord is the note that changes each time so F->Eb->D, then the changing notes can be considered as passing tones, since they are not being used in a functional progression. For example, if the key center where this happens in F minor, then the Eb Ab C F chord could be changing the F minor to a ii chord in Eb. You don't mention what comes next, and that is the crucial chord to tell us if the Dm7-5  is functional or not. If the D moves down to Db or C, then we are still dealing with passing tones. If the D moves to a Bb7 chord, or a G7 chord, then it is functional.

So, if the D is part of the baseline, then it is not Fm6. Hope this helps!